# how to differentiate the same color objects with different intensity?

Tags: opencv, object-detection

There are 3 leather pieces of Brown color.Among them one is dark brown in color.I have to highlight that odd piece(dark brown piece).The procedure which I followed in my code is:

1. converted given image to HSV.
2. checked the saturation range(S value) as well as the brightness range (V value) of the odd piece and other two light intensity pieces.

But the problem is, The odd piece values(both s and v value ranges) overlaps with the other two pieces(light intensity) values.

So,which color model best suits for this problem ?

If, Illumination changes the values gets changed again,How should I tackle this problem?
What type of Camera should I use ?

Comment: this is a very difficult problem that cannot be just easily solved. You might get some suggestions; but lightning changes of objects are subjets of whole master thesises etc...

Comment: I suggest you to take a look around for the existing literature and look into that...

Comment: Can you please provide some sample images?